# How can I get all the file names under one folder using gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

How can I get all the file names under one file folder? and foreach all the file names? using gremlin command

Comment: SO is not a code-for-hire service. What have you tried? Where is your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gremlin is a graph traversal language. It doesn't have specific commands for reading the file system. You would just use the features of your programming language to do that. With Groovy, you could just do:

```
gremlin> new File("data").eachFile(groovy.io.FileType.FILES) { println it.name }
tinkerpop-modern.json
tinkerpop-classic.kryo
...
script-input.groovy
```

Comment: There's a lot of resources at http://tinkerpop.apache.org/ but start with http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/getting-started/ and http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/